# If Biden weren't a 2020 candidate, would a quid pro quo to investigate corruption be impeachable?

Tags: united-states, constitution, trump-impeachment

The US government uses quid pro quos (QPQs) regularly to enforce its political will on entities it does business with: hostage negotiating, pushing of ideals, conflict resolution,  etc, etc, ad nauseam.

1. If Joe Biden weren’t a 2020 presidential candidate and assuming QPQs to investigate just another politician actually happened, would it still be impeachable?
2. If the answer to number 1 is yes, under what circumstances, if any,  is it not an impeachable offense for a president to investigate corruption of a fellow politician?

Comment: I think the question to ask is if he wasn't a candidate would there even have been a request to investigate it in the first place.

Comment: @JoeW such a question would be a question about internal motivations of people.  It would have to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @grovkin I think it is appropriate considering the line of thought that this is being done to a political opponent in the first place in this question.

Comment: @JoeW why would that make it a question that is not about a politician's internal motivations?

Comment: @JoeW, the line of thought is around the Constitutionally protected Due Process of Law, Burden of Proof, and the Scope of Authority relative to investigating political corruption on foreign soil.

Comment: The government uses "do ut des". Quid pro quo is Latin for "mistaking something for something else".

Comment: A better question would be whether, if he becomes President in 2020, whether the Republicans will immediately move to impeach him.

Comment: How is the president holding up congressional approved funding in order to get an ally to start an investigation a due process of law?

Comment: Also important is whether or not it's even impeachable to begin with.

Comment: @motoDrizzt "quid pro quo" only means "something for something else."  There is no verb.  It *could* mean mistaking something for something else, but more commonly it means, as it does in US law, *exchanging* something for something else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the law cited as the reason for an impeachment article is rendered unconstitutional, does that nullify the impeachment article?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/46222/if-the-law-cited-as-the-reason-for-an-impeachment-article-is-rendered-unconstitu)

Comment: You are assuming that it is impeachable now. That is what the Democrats and Republicans are debating up on Capital Hill

Comment: @JoeW "If he wasn't a candidate would there even have been a request to investigate it in the first place" -- Trivially, yes. Allegations of corruption are not uncommonly leveled and acted on against people who are not currently running for political office. There are also other players implicated in the very same request for investigation, who are not running for a prominent political office.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[By the constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_in_the_United_States#Constitutional_provisions), the whole impeachment process from the start of an impeachment investigation to the conviction in the Senate is the sole prerogative of Congress. Specifically (quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment_in_the_United_States#Constitutional_provisions)):

> Article I, Section 2, Clause 5 provides:
>
> The House of Representatives ... shall have the sole Power of Impeachment.
>
> Article I, Section 3, Clauses 6 and 7 provides:
>
> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments. When sitting for that Purpose, they shall be on Oath or Affirmation. When the President of the United States is tried, the Chief Justice shall preside: And no Person shall be convicted without the Concurrence of two-thirds of the Members present.
>
> [...]
>
> Article II, Section 4 provides:
>
> The President, Vice President and all civil Officers of the United States, shall be removed from Office on Impeachment for, and Conviction of, Treason, Bribery, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors.

Those *"high crimes and misdemeanors"* are described in Federalist No. 65, [as quoted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_crimes_and_misdemeanors#United_States):

> In Federalist No. 65, Alexander Hamilton said, "those offences which proceed from the misconduct of public men, or, in other words, from the abuse or violation of some public trust. They are of a nature which may with peculiar propriety be denominated political, as they relate chiefly to injuries done immediately to the society itself."

So whether something is an impeachable offense depends on whether Congress deems it a high crime or misdemeanor. That term is somewhat subjective. It can be argued that it fits the definition above, but ultimately it depends on who's in the Congress which changes over time. Even if we know who's in the Congress, we can only guess how each member is going to vote in this hypothetical case.

So to answer the question: it may be or it may not be. It depends on many factors which we cannot determine.

Comment: @grovkin please elaborate. I've edited in the clauses from the constitution which both use the word *sole* to establish these powers.

Comment: @grovkin thanks, I've elaborated. I agree that it's not a carte-blanche, but going by the description in the Federalist Papers, it could be. Whether this specific hypothetical scenario is depends on Congress.

Comment: Exactly.  Congress can impeach on basically any grounds it wants.  Whether the "quid pro quo" is actually a violation of law is irrelevant to the actual impeachment process.  It would only come into play if Trump is removed from office, and then is tried in court for illegal acts.  (Indeed, I think he could be tried after leaving office in the normal manner, though you'd have to ask on the legal site for a more authoritative opinion than mine :-))

Comment: @jamesqf well it does specifically mention bribery. If you read the federal bribery statute it says it's illegal for a public official to corruptly demand anything of value in return for being influenced in the performance of any official act.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica "anything of value" is a legal term.  It's not the same thing as anything of value in the plain-English sense.  It's been made more precise by the campaign-finance case law.  Effectively it means anything which can be commercially bought or sold.  So, for example, volunteering one's services is not "a thing of value."

Comment: In other words, impeachment is potentially as partisan and as arbitrary as the composition of the House allows.

Comment: Hamilton's quote seems to deflate the argument of legitimacy of articles of impeachment on the basis alone of Congressional determination. While Congress has the sole power of impeachment, an impeachable offense in Hamilton's view would of necessity be something that is detrimental to the public and society at large, and not only in the eyes of other politicians.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are asking about a political act (impeachment) as contrasted with prosecution of illegal acts (that are judged and tried by the judiciary), one can only speculate on the actions of the politicians. With that said I will speculate:

Your Q#1: Yes, IMO, an impeachment resolution could involve a QPQ investigation demand  centered around **any** politician, and potentially **any non-politician** for that matter.

Your Q#2: The circumstances are whatever the House of Representatives, by majority vote, decides are impeachable.

Comment: If one of the three highest authorities in the government can't investigate political corruption, how does political corruption ever get resolved?

Comment: @thepip3r What are you talking about?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your assertion is that any qpq by the president to investigate corruption in a foreign country of anyone would be an impeachable offense, correct?  If so, then how does corruption on foreign soil get exposed and resolved?

Comment: @thepip3r "how does corruption on foreign soil get exposed and resolved?" I think that was asked and answered in the Kent deposition. MR. PERRY: Okay. So would you say that if the United States was interested in pursuing justice of a past incident, of an incident that occurred in the past regarding someone that had a political office, is that off limits to the United States of America?

Comment: @thepip3r MR. KENT: I think if there's any criminal nexus for any activity involving the U.S., that U.S. law enforcement by all means should pursue that case, and if there's an international connection, that we have the mechanisms to ask either through Department of Justice MLAT in writing or through the presence of individuals representing the FBI, our legal attaches, to engage foreign governments directly based on our concerns that there had been some criminal act violating U.S. law.

Comment: @Lag, I agree and knew that was the answer but who does the FBI work for?

Comment: @thepip3r the FBI works indirectly for the president. If the president thinks that someone has broken the law, the president should direct the attorney general to investigate. The president has no business attempting to compel another country to pursue a particular investigation.  Pressure may properly be brought to bear on a country that refuses to cooperate with an FBI investigation, but in this case the was no FBI investigation.  If only foreign laws were violated, evidence may be passed to the appropriate foreign authorities, but then it is theirs to do with--or not--what they will.

Comment: @thepip3r Just to be clear, the events that occurred here are: A corrupt man who was *not* investigating corruption was fired after pressure from the US.  That man blames Biden.  There is no actual corruption involving Biden and Ukraine.  President Trump tries to pressure Ukraine's president to manufacture a fake investigation into Biden and to give a public statement about it.  He doesnt care much about the investigation itself, just the public statement that he can use to slander Biden.  None of this has anything to do with investigating corruption, except for Trump's corruption.

Comment: @Tal, if you believe that, then you're being sorely misled.  In fact, the entire last week's Democrat-led Impeachment hearing did nothing but condemn Ukraine, as a whole, as a cesspool of corruption--explicitly affirmed by the testimony given by Kent, Taylor, and Yavanovich.  And with Barisma being called out by name by the Ukrainian diplomatic team as being notorious for its head being a corrupt oligarch.  So... If everyone understands Ukraine is corrupt, you're contending that the former VP got his son elected to the board of a notoriously corrupt institution out of??? ... Ignorance?

Comment: "Biden's son" is a 49 year old man with his own consulting firm.  You seem to be implying that Biden somehow intentionally put his son onto a corporate board by encouraging Ukraine to get rid of a corrupt investigator who specifically *was not* investigating corruption over a corruption investigation that was already closed by that corrupt investigator at the time.  How does this make sense?  The Obama admin was pressuring Ukraine to actually investigate corruption.  Trump doesnt care about the corruption.  Only the one specific company with a connection to a political rival after the fact.

Comment: @thepip3r, do you have any evidence that VP Biden "got his son elected" to the Burisma board? Did VP Biden get the other Americans elected to this board?

Comment: @BobE, atTal,  If you look over Hunter Biden's entire career, it has mirrored Joe Biden's career (see China, Ukraine, etc.).  In fact, two weeks after Joe Biden visited Ukraine, Hunter Biden was appointed to the board of a notoriously corrupt energy company.  --No, I have no proof he got his son elected but his career wreaks of corruption and at the very least, is entirely unethical.  IMO, the lack of concern for even the appearance of impropriety is a problem.  Could it be a coincidence that Hunter Biden's career has mirrored his father's?  ...sure.  Epstein could've also killed himself.

Comment: @thepip3r, OK, so now we all know that yours is simply rank speculation, without the benefit of any corroboration - why should anyone take your comments seriously?

Comment: @Tal, Do you remember 'quid pro quo'?  That's the language the Democrats spent weeks in private chambers coming up with and abandoned after last week's testimony.  That's why I asked this question however-many days ago it was.  Speaking of 'quid pro quo' something the Democrats started a Presidential impeachment over: https://www.foreign.senate.gov/imo/media/doc/5-4-18 Menendez joint letter to General Prosecutor of Ukraine on Mueller investigation.pdf:  "The article notes that your office considered these cases as too politically sensitive and potentially jeopardizing U.S. financial and...

Comment: @Tal, "military aid to Ukraine."

Comment: @BobE, if you're comfortable with the duly elected President being impeached under highly questionable, and so far, completely uncorroborated allegations--who's allegations are changing every week as each new allegation keeps holding no water, why should any of this be taken seriously?  This whole process is at best, 'rank speculation' and at worst, a play to remove a sitting President under false pretenses.

Comment: You haven't been watching the House hearings... Lots of evidence offered by republican witnesses - I could be persuaded to give the pres. a pass on just this Ukraine  issue - excuse it as an uninformed mistake.  But Pres has publicly acknowledged that he sees nothing wrong with asking foreign gov'ts to interfer with our electoral process - which means he's Ok with doing it again and again

Comment: @BobE, You are correct, I haven't been watching--I've been listening in my headphones.  To be fair, asking another government for information on someone, presidential candidate or no, is not interference--it's information.  Interference is only possible if the info holds water.  And since you bring it up, how do you feel about the uncorroborated Steele Dossier, pushed by the Russian-manned/Clinton-funded, Fusion GPS that started the whole 'Russian Investigation' into then-candidate Trump?  Exactly what you're crying foul for with Trump, the Clintons did to him in the run-up to 2016.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101283/discussion-between-thepip3r-and-bobe).

Comment: @BobE A pretty solid list of the family corruption that's apparently rampant in Biden's family due to Joe's political career:  https://nypost.com/2020/01/18/how-five-members-of-joe-bidens-family-got-rich-through-his-connections/

Comment: @thepip3r - let's cut to the chase (cuz I'm not going to wade through Schweizer's book) - have any of the Biden's been convicted of or charged with corruption?

Comment: @BobE, we'll see in the next few years.  ...and if you're insinuating that because they haven't gone through the court system, they're not corrupt, then I guess Harvey Weinstein and Jeff Epstein aren't pedophiles either by the same standard.

Comment: @thepip3r - you may have missed it, but both Weinstein and Epstein were/are credibly charged with crimes.  If you can show me where the Bidens have been credibly **charged**, then you may have an point. Till then...

Comment: @BobE, according to the 6th Amendment, you are innocent until proven guilty.  So, there's no such thing as "credibly charged" and therefore, is no better than not charged at all.  You appear to be stuck in a logical and legal chicken and egg problem.  When I'm saying they're corrupt, I'm saying after working in government for almost 20 years, there are very clear conflicts of interest that reeks of impropriety and corruption that should be investigated.  I wonder if you're as accommodating with your presumption of innocence with regard to Bush/Cheney and Halliburton and it's subsidiaries.

Comment: @thepip3r This has become tiresome and STUPID.  Credibly charged - as in being formally charged by a prosecutor or law enforcement authority. As contrasted with being charged by Joe Six-Pack  or  Alex Jones or a some political hack of a writer.   Get back to me when you can identify when and by what AUTHORITY the Biden family has been credibly charged.

Comment: @BobE, Finally something we agree on--giving a legal 101 on SO is tiresome and you still don't seem to get it but that's OK.  Let me try to illuminate the paradox you're in.  How can someone get 'credibly charged' if you're always above suspicion before said charge can happen?  Cute circular logic btw.  Additionally, if you're 'credibly charged' but are proven not-guilty, does that mean the charge wasn't 'credible' in the first place?  And are you still damned forever in BobE's world because you once had a 'credible charge' that turned out to be not-so-credible?  Btw, who are Alex J and Joe S?

Comment: @thepip3r Get back to me when you can identify when and by what AUTHORITY the Biden family has been credibly charged

Answer (score 3):

At its core, the Presidential impeachment process is not about justice, fair trial, fact finding, etc. It's strictly about convincing an overwhelming majority of voters that the President should be impeached, so that 2/3 of Senators would be inclined to vote for impeachment. Back in 1974, Nixon's support [levels dropped to 24%](https://www.newsweek.com/donald-trump-richard-nixon-impeachment-polling-1464494) and the majority of the country was in favour of removing him from office, so he resigned as a last ditch attempt to save face. On the other hand Clinton had a [73% rating at the height of the impeachment](https://www.cnn.com/ALLPOLITICS/stories/1998/12/20/impeachment.poll/) and the vote in Senate predictably failed.

If enough voters want Trump out, he'll be out, no matter the charges. If enough want him to stay, he'll keep the White House at least until January 2021. Everything else is superficial. Of course, impeachments do work differently for other positions such as judges, Congressmen and Senators, but the President is unique for being the most high-profile person in the country, so Congress won't remove them without considering approval ratings first. Otherwise the party voting for impeachment risks sinking the electoral prospects for the next decade, as their core voters become disillusioned.

Comment: Do you have evidence to support that that was also the intention with which impeachment was added to the constitution? I mean, it doesn't just apply to presidents, it also applies to judges. Surely judges don't need to maintain certain approval ratings?

Comment: @JJ  edited my post to clarify this

Comment: I get your point, but I don't know to which extent you're saying this is a point. Are you arguing ratings are the main point of a presidential impeachment or are you arguing this is an unavoidable side-effect?

Comment: @JJ I'm arguing that Senators know all too well that impeaching a popular president would spell doom for their own re-election, so they'll never do it

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I agree with that. Suppose we take President Trump as an example. He's popular in many states with a significant Republican base. Suppose a Republican Senator votes to impeach him, then it only affects their position if they are up for reelection and if there's a Republican alternative (assuming it's a fairly safe seat). It's not like supporters of President Trump are suddenly going to vote Democrat because the Republican incumbent voted to impeach him. I think your answer applies in some cases, but certainly not all of them.

Comment: @JJ every swing state is indeed likely to vote Democrat if the Republican party screws up too much. Republicans won't necessarily vote Democrat, they could just become disillusioned and stay home. Not to mention the fact that Democrats could taunt the Republican impeachment for at least a decade to come.

Answer (score 3):

Part of the question boils down to "what is impeachable".  One definition, from Gerald Ford (then a Rep) is "whatever a majority of the House believes on a given day".  So, yes, it could still be impeachable.

I suspect the question was really about what 'should be' impeachable, which in a way, cannot be truly answered, as its a matter of opinion.

I would argue the heart of the impeachment (in addition to life time of corruption allegations, nearly 3 years as president pushing the boundaries (putting it mildly) to a degree rarely seen before is "abuse of office".  The Office of the President comes with great powers (currently far greater than the Framers seemed to want, if you actually read Article II).

To use those powers in any way that is more to the benefit of the President, no matter how indirectly, than it is to the benefit of the Country is an abuse of power.

To me, any question like this can be answered by assuming we live in the kind of country the constitution is meant to prevent us from being...Imagine we lived in a total dictatorship.  Would you want the Leader of that country to use all the powers at his disposal to try to go after people for personal reasons?  Its pretty scary, right?

Now, seeing the link to the personal benefit of the President is clearer when its a potential election rival, but what if its just someone he didn't like?  Does that make it any less scary when you pretend we are in a North Korea style Stalinist state?  To me, its even scarier.

In this way, it is not WHO he had investigated that makes something impeachable, but WHY.  Note, he asked for Biden to be investigated by the Ukrainians.  It is NOT the presidents job to uphold any laws both those of the US, and it is not the Ukrainians job to uphold US law (yes, there is a Mutual Legal Assistance Treaty in place, but then why were the formal mechanics of this not used?).

Answer (score 0):

Other answers already cover the *"impeachment can be anything"* angle. But let's cover why Trump's alleged actions are sufficiently unpopular (and also criminal), to warrant impeachment:

1. It is improper for the president of the United States to coerce/extort/bribe a foreign government to investigate a U.S. citizen.
2. It is improper for the president to corruptly interfere in the U.S. presidential election.
3. It is explicitly impeachable to ask for something of personal value to himself in return for executing his duties (Section 4 of Article 2: Treason, *Bribery*, or other high Crimes and Misdemeanors).

If he instead coerced a foreign government to launch a political investigation into a different citizen (instead of asking for cooperation in an existing investigation), e.g. Russia & Edward Snowden, it would still be an abuse of power, but due to the absence of 2. and 3. the case for impeachment would be far weaker.

Comment: Allegation 1 seems unfounded. Since when does nationality make a request to investigate someone's conduct "improper"? The U.S. has signed a resolution with Ukraine to assist each other in investigations, implying that the nationality of a suspect does not grant him immunity from investigation by either country.
Allegations 2. and 3. ignore that the investigation was warranted by evident corruption, which shuts down the "personal value" and "election interference" arguments.

Comment: @pygosceles You misread "coerce/extort/bribe". You also introduced an unwarranted and repeatedly debunked claim of "the investigation was warranted by evident corruption". The very fact that the legitimate channels for legal assistance you refer to exist - and would most certainly be used if there was evident corruption -  should make it perfectly obvious to all but the most partisan observer that using entirely different channels, combining them with coercion, and trying to hide everything about it, is as far removed from "legitimate" as it gets.

Comment: Requesting an investigation is not coercion and the president of Ukraine testified there was no quid pro quo, no conditions, therefore this cannot possibly be construed as a bribe. Even the House Democrats dropped this allegation from their articles of impeachment because there is no case for it.
"debunked" is a highly partisan judgment and is not borne out by available information. There is abundant evidence of misconduct including an ACTUAL quid pro quo bribe to deflect investigation. This question needs resolution.

Comment: What are the "legitimate channels" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If Joe Biden weren’t a 2020 presidential candidate and assuming QPQs to investigate just another politician actually happened, would
>      it still be impeachable?

The allegation of abuse of power, bribery, corruption, you-name-it etc. on President Trump's part hinges on whether or not Hunter Biden is guilty as suspected or even whether there is sufficient information to **warrant** an investigation into his conduct.
If there were zero incriminating evidence against Hunter and zero actual corruption on his part, then a suspicion of using the powers of the office of the president to target an opponent might hold some water. Otherwise, the investigation is warranted and it is simply the executive branch doing its work of enforcing the law and working together with foreign governments to eliminate corruption. The US and Ukraine are to cooperate in such investigations, per [a resolution signed with Ukraine back in 1998](https://www.congress.gov/treaty-document/106th-congress/16/document-text).

> 2. If the answer to number 1 is yes, under what circumstances, if any, is it not an impeachable offense for a president to investigate
>      corruption of a fellow politician?

I'll use this as an opportunity to address the **impeachability** premise. Impeachability according to JJ's answer is as arbitrary and potentially partisan as the composition of the House of Representatives will allow.
In terms of the intent of the Founding Fathers, however, high crimes and misdemeanors must be recognized by and actually be impactful/hurtful towards the people themselves, not just in the eyes of a house full of politicians. While not directly codified in the Constitutional process of impeachment, Hamilton's quote implies the necessity of popular support for impeachment. **Impeachability** in a moral sense is therefore clearly a matter of actual, not imagined offense, and negative impact on society at large. The congressional power of impeachment is intended to reflect this reality, but nothing in the Constitution explicitly forces it to. The intent is that politicians will be held to account by the people they are supposed to represent should they choose to abuse the powers of their office. The existence of latency allowing for a temporary disconnect between the will of the people and their representatives is a fact of life, as is the eventually unavoidable reality of that accountability.

In rational society, an investigation that is warranted is perfectly allowable and should be pursued by priority according to its potential gravity. Such an investigation and its issuers are perfectly harmless to society, regardless of what the investigation turns up.
Only an unwarranted investigation or a reversal of sound priorities in terms of what to investigate could be an abuse of power or obstruction of justice.

According to justice (which is the duty of the Executive branch to enforce), a **warranted** investigation into corruption of any person, **politician or not**, is *helpful, not hurtful* to society and therefore is not impeachable in the most important sense.

Comment: Any feedback from downvoters (or upvoters or nonvoters)?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, it would... if both the House and Senate decide its impeachable. Impeachment is governed by somewhat subjective criteria, but it's in the Constitution. Without going into detail, if enough representatives in both houses really don't like the current president, they can remove him via impeachment. Proof of a crime really isn't necessary.

The House can vote for articles of impeachment... a sort-of indictment, only requiring a simple majority to pass.

The Senate holds the actual trial. If 2/3 of the Senators vote for impeachment, the president is out.

In today's situation, it is quite possible that the articles of impeachment might pass the House. Getting a 2/3 majority in the Senate to convict is unlikely, if for no other reason that removing any president is a highly destabilizing event in itself.

Looking back to the last unscheduled presidential departure, Nixon, the Democrats won big in 1976. But, the generally uncertain nature of a president being forced out of office, combined with Carter's massive tax increases, had investors fleeing the stock market for bonds and gold, which pushed the country into a deep recession in the late 1970's, with unemployment higher than 2008-2009.

For which the Democrats were held responsible in the 1980 election... leading to Republicans dominating the federal government for the next 12 years.

Impeachment should not be taken lightly. The unintended consequences can be severe.

If Joe Biden wasn't a 2020 candidate, there is a possibility that the investigation into his and his son's dealings with Ukraine would have moved forward.

Even discounting the right wing exaggerations, a US VP's son with no management experience at all and a somewhat irresponsible past including getting booted from the Army for drug use, suddenly getting a $600k-900k a year job as a director of a foreign energy company... looks like an attempt by that company or country to purchase Dad's influence.

Dad using the power of the VP's office to exert influence beneficial to his son, and bragging about it on video, does nothing to paint that situation in a more ethical light.

Comment: To be clear, Joe Biden didn't "brag on video" about "exerting influence beneficial to his son". You might want to look deeper into what Biden did "brag" about: the removal from office of Viktor Shokin, the now former prosecutor general of Ukraine, whom the US Government, EU, IMF, the World Bank, Ukrainian prosecutors, Ukrainian MPs and anti-corruption Ukrainians wanted gone because of his corruption. A man who Trump has described as "very good" and "very fair"...

Comment: Biden Sr. went to the Ukraine on orders of the US government to get rid of Shokin. He succeeded, and bragged about it. Not half as much as Trump would. At that point in time, Biden jr. had no connection to the Ukraine.